# JavaScript array or object checking - code improvements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement

I receive data => these data could be array of object or just a object.
I write some code, but maybe there is a way to make this code more sexy, clear, or shorter plus without any errors

Here is the code:

```
export const CalculateIt = (props) => {
  const conversionValues = []
  if (props) {
    if (props.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        const clicks = props[i]?.insights?.[0].inline_link_clicks
        const actionsNumber = props[i]?.insights?.[0]?.actions?.length || 0
        let result = 0
        if (clicks && actionsNumber) {
          result = devideNumbers(clicks, actionsNumber, 8)
        }
        conversionValues.push(result)
      }
      return conversionValues
    }
    const clicks = props?.insights?.[0].inline_link_clicks
    const actionsNumber = props?.insights?.[0]?.actions?.length || 0
    let result = 0
    if (clicks && actionsNumber) {
      result = devideNumbers(clicks, actionsNumber)
    }

    return conversionValues.push(result)
  }
}
```

As you can see there you can find some parts of the code that are similar like:

```
const clicks = props[i]?.insights?.[0].inline_link_clicks

and 

const clicks = props?.insights?.[0].inline_link_clicks
```

Is it possible to write it more smart?

Best

Comment: can you send sample data to test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably move the common code in a function:

```
function getResult(data) {
    const clicks = data?.insights?.[0].inline_link_clicks
    const actionsNumber = data?.insights?.[0]?.actions?.length || 0
    let result = 0
    if (clicks && actionsNumber) {
       result = devideNumbers(clicks, actionsNumber, 8)
    }
    return result;
}
```

And use the helper function in your original function:

```
export const CalculateIt = (props) => {
  const conversionValues = []
  if (props) {
    if (props.constructor === Array) {
      props.forEach((item) => conversionValues.push(getResult(item)))
    } else {
       conversionValues.push(getResult(props));
    }
    return conversionValues;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks sexy! Thanks. Just checking it I have one more question: 

```
for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        conversionValues.push(getResult(props[i]))
      }
```

This for loop could we write shorter using JavaScript to have the similar achievement? 
Just is it possible to write it shorter :)

Comment: @TimeBuy yes definitely, put in a forEach and it'll look cleaner. 
Will edit the answer above

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can force all `data` into a one-dimensional array and safe work with  array of objects only.

Is this code sexy enough?

```js
const obj = {id: 1, val: 1};
const arr = [{id: 1, val: 1},{id: 2, val: 2},{id: 3, val: 3}];

const normalize = (data) => [data].flat();
console.log(normalize(obj)[0]);
console.log(normalize(arr)[0]);

// -------------------
// and you can use this approach in code:
const getResult = (obj) => obj.val * 10;
const CalculateIt = (props) => [props].flat().map(getResult);

console.log(CalculateIt(obj));
console.log(CalculateIt(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```